# Posting data to an aspx form from an android app

Tags: android, asp.net

I want to send data from my app to http://studentssp.wit.ie/Timetables/POSTT.aspx that page and I'm not sure how to do that. All that I have tried atm is adding some of the form values to the url to see if that changes anything, but it hasn't. e.g. I put cboSchool=EP (the name value of the select is cboSchool and the value of the School of Adult Education is EP) into the url to see if it would only load information regarding that school. http://studentssp.wit.ie/Timetables/POSTT.aspx?cboSchool=EP
I'm knew to android and know nothing about aspx.

Answer (score 0):

This should get your started:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);  
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", "value1"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2", "value2")); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name3", "value3"));   
// etc...
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I think that should work for what you're trying to do. I have TIMEOUT_MS set to 10000 (so, 10 seconds)

Then you can read out the server's response using something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent
```

Comment: When I print out the response that I get, there is no changes in the page. In the department section only "DA - Adult Education" should be returned, not all the departments. In the nameValuePairs I have nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cboSchool", "EP"));

Comment: I believe you have to get the selected value from the drop-down and in this case it should be DA - Adult Education

Comment: I'm not following. I passed the value EP and it should only return DA - Adult Education, but it ignores it (no matter what I send/try to receive).

Comment: It seems that the whole httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);  part doesn't work. The webapge is returned but nothing has changed at all on it. I have tried it with a few different websites and nothing changed. Why?

Answer (score 0):

1- you talk about mobile application based on web , so if you need to interact with server side , you need web service .

please check the web service you need to integrate with site you need .

2- most of web service will be (Restful format ,SOAP). 
Restful is easier , you can parse data with any open source parse SAX , DOM for XML format , 
or Json Parser for json .

i will give you simple example :

this is a currency converter API , and we will sent the parameters in URL this is mean http Get request , 
Like :
http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100GBP=?USD

there is "?hl=en&q=1GBP=?USD "
any parameter have 2 parts is 1-key  2- value .
h1 is key  , en is value .
q is key ,  1GEP=?USD is value .

and the respone will be in json format Like 
{lhs: "100 British pounds",rhs: "161.47 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}
you can see this is [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) for parsing json .

i hope this help you?